# Default Convention: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

Tags: iphone, conventions, uiinterfaceorientation

When adding the UIInterfaceOrientation key to the info.plist file, is there a conventional default value for the initial app state (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)?

And which do you typically use when starting in landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the original document where I read this (It's one of the apple guideline documents you read when you first start) but it said the preferred landscape was with the volume buttons on the bottom. So I think that's UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

**correction:** UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. Always get the 2 mixed up.

Comment: According to this, volume buttons on the bottom is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: http://blog.sallarp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/slide1.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a conventional default value for landscape orientation. Its upto the developer but I think its better to have `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible for a user to choose which orientation it would like to use. 
I prefer UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.